# How to use useEffect when there are dependencies I don't care about?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, use-effect

```
  useCallback(() => {
    async function awaitAllPendingTxs() {
      const txReceiptPromises = txsPending.map((tx) => {
        return provider.waitForTransaction(tx.hash);
      });

      const txReciepts = await Promise.all(txReceiptPromises);

      txReciepts.forEach((tx) =>
        dispatch(actions.rmTxsPending(tx.transactionHash))
      );
    }

    awaitAllPendingTxs();
  }, [provider]);
```

I only want this to run when the app first loads.

And more specifically when `provider` is available. `provider` is initialized as `null`. At some point when the app first loads, `provider` is initialized. That's when I want this to run.

But the React hooks plugin is telling me to add `dispatch` and `txsPending`.

I don't want the code to run when `txsPending` and `dispatch` changes. And yet, I need these variables and functions in the `useCallback`.

If I add `txsPending` and `dispatch` to the dep array, won't the codeblock be called three times?

Once when dispatch is created, and everytime `txsPending` is changed (`txsPending` is localstate)? Which I don't want.

How is `useCallback` dep array satisfied here? While also making sure it only runs when I want it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a best practice not to lie about your dependency array when using `useEffect` because it can cause problems later on.

try this instead:

```
const [avoidExtraCall, setAvoidExtraCall] = useState(false);

useCallback(() => {
  if(provider && !avoidExtraCall){
    async function awaitAllPendingTxs() {
      const txReceiptPromises = txsPending.map((tx) => {
        return provider.waitForTransaction(tx.hash);
      });
    
      const txReciepts = await Promise.all(txReceiptPromises);
    
      txReciepts.forEach((tx) =>
        dispatch(actions.rmTxsPending(tx.transactionHash))
      );
    }
  
    awaitAllPendingTxs();
    setAvoidExtraCall(true);
  }
}, [provider, txsPending]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to store (or clone) `txsPending`, in a `useRef`, and update the value in the proper time, so that `useEffect` could always have the latest value.

For `dispatch` I guess it's value is always static, so it can be safely captured by the closure; however the eslint is not parsing it correctly. I think you could ignore it, if you accept keeping the eslint warnings, otherwise you might also need to clone it in a `useRef`.

P.S. I think you mean `useEffect` instead of `useCallback`? Since you dont assign the result of `useCallback` to any variable for later use?

The codes:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function awaitAllPendingTxs() {
      // This line, use a ref
      const txReceiptPromises = txsPendingRef.current.map((tx) => {
      ...
      // ignore warning, or use something like dispatchRef.current
      txReciepts.forEach((tx) =>
        dispatch(actions.rmTxsPending(tx.transactionHash))
      );
    }

    awaitAllPendingTxs();
  }, [provider]);
```